# Wrap ListView inside a TitledPane without getting a scrollbat

Tags: listview, javafx, scrollbar

I've been trying to figure out for awhile how to have a ListView be contained inside TitledPane and have the TitledPane expand to the full height of the ListView without generating a scroll bar. Below is some code I modified from
[JavaFX accordion with multiple open panes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386268/javafx-accordion-with-multiple-open-panes) to show the problem. When the below code is run, all the TitledPanes are collapsed and there is only 1 scrollbar, but as titledpanes are open, a second or third scrollbar is created, as the titledpanes dont expand to fully show their contents.

Is there a way to force the TitledPanes to expaned to fully show their contents?The only thing I can think of would be to add a changelistener  on every titledpane to grab its contents and add up all the sizes, but this soon gets very messy and unwieldy. I would think that there would be a really simple solution, I just can't see it.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackedPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox stackedTitledPanes = createStackedTitledPanes();
        stackedTitledPanes.setPrefSize(410, 600);
        ScrollPane scroll = makeScrollable(stackedTitledPanes);
        scroll.setPrefSize(410, 600);

        stage.setTitle("Test Case");
        Scene scene = new Scene(scroll);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Here I create the top level TitledPanes and start filling them up with listviews of more titledpanes

```
    private VBox createStackedTitledPanes() {
        final VBox stackedTitledPanes = new VBox();
        final ListView<TitledPane> listView = new ListView<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            final TitledPane newPane = new TitledPane();
            newPane.setContent(createSubPane());
            newPane.setText("Pane " + i);
            listView.getItems().add(newPane);
            newPane.setExpanded(false);
        }
        stackedTitledPanes.getChildren().add(listView);
        VBox.setVgrow(listView, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return stackedTitledPanes;
    }

    private Node createSubPane() {
        final ListView<TitledPane> paneListView = new ListView<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            final TitledPane subPane = new TitledPane();
            subPane.setText("SubPane " + i);

            final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                listView.getItems().add("Item " + j);
            }
            subPane.setContent(listView);
            subPane.setExpanded(false);
            paneListView.getItems().add(subPane);
        }
        return paneListView;
    }

    private ScrollPane makeScrollable(final VBox node) {
        final ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
        scroll.setContent(node);
        return scroll;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

I would have also added a pic, but I need more rep. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a ListView without a scrollPane?

Comment: I just want the single most outter scrollbar, when a titledpane is expanded, if its content at too large, it gives it a scrollbar. So, in the code, there are three separate scrollbars instead of just a single outter scrollbar.